# Add a link stylesheet dynamically in the <head>

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom, crash

How to add a link stylesheet reference to the head of a document ?

I've found this code but it's not working with all browsers, it crashes my IE7 :

```
var ss = document.createElement("link");
ss.type = "text/css";
ss.rel = "stylesheet";
ss.href = "style.css";
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(ss);
```

Thanks

Comment: hmm I've used this method before, and all went well in IE7

Comment: Your code works in IE6 and IE7 for me.  Could it be some other part of the page that is causing the issue?

Comment: Ok i'll triple check with my colleagues later, thank you for your concern.

Comment: Tom and the others, i think other scripts maybe interfering but there is no warning, no error message. What should i do if this is the case ? Delete this issue ?

Comment: This method worked fine for me in Firefox, IE 6, 7, and 8

Comment: Try: `document.body.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(ss);`

Answer (score -5, accepted):

That was a simple cross reference javascript bug. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 10):

Internet explorer will support innerHTML, though it adds reflow this would work:

```
var headHTML = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].innerHTML;
headHTML    += '<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].innerHTML = headHTML;
```

Comment: Interresting, you code work only on firefox.

Comment: I haven't tested this out, you mean to say this doesn't work in internet Explorer?

Comment: Ah. Thats bad, I shouldn't have got a vote for my answer.

Comment: It works for Firefox, this is still a good answer.

Comment: I don't have any proof for my theory, but I don't think modifying the innerHTML of the document's HEAD element is a good idea.

Comment: it works on chrome

Answer (score 2):

In IE, you could try the createStyleSheet method?  That takes URL as a parameter.  I don't know whether there is an equivalent in FF/chrome though..

--Senthil