# Adding External Stylesheet using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, external

I need to add an link to an external css file in my header using an external javascript file. Don't ask why; I just need to do it. `document.write()` doesn't work btw.

Comment: You should be able to add a `link` node to the DOM same as you would add a `p` or `div` node to the document.  Have you tried that?  The question is whether the style would be applied.  I really don't know.... Good question. Someone tried it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/512070/add-a-link-stylesheet-dynamically-in-the-head

Comment: @Ray Toal - yup, the styles will be applied once you insert the link element on the head.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
var element = document.createElement("link");
element.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
element.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
element.setAttribute("href", "external.css");
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(element);
```

Comment: Note that IE isn't always happy about `link` tags being inserted this way. Check for `document.createStylesheet` and use if it eists.

Comment: honestly I don't care too much for IE so not a problem. Thanks Ben!

Comment: Use `document.head.appendChild(element);` instead of `document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(element);`

Answer (score 5):

Alternative one liner:

```
document.head.insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeend', '<link rel=stylesheet href=/ext.css>' );
```

Comment: Nice! This is the neatest solution I've found so far :)