# How to make a browser download external files after having loaded a page?

Tags: browser, stylesheet, pageload

Alright, my question is pretty simple. Suppose I have a homepage that is not linked to any external stylesheets, all its styles being either inline or internal, how do I do so that AFTER the homepage has been downloaded and displayed, the browser then downloads any necessary (specified) external stylesheets. Is this possible?

Thank you.

Comment: This question might give you a hint: [link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/512070/add-a-link-stylesheet-dynamically-in-the-head

Answer (score 0):

**Try This:**

```
<head>
   <script type='text/javascript'>
      function addstyle()
      {
        document.getElementById('style').href='style.css';
      }
   </script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="">
</head>
<body onload="addstyle()">
   <h1>Welcome</h1>
   <p>Hello whats up</p>
   <p>Hope you will have a great day</p>
</body>
```