# write css link relationship and apply css through dom on window.onLoad

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm in an environment were the head is delivered and cannot statically write to it. I only get to write to after the body tag, i can't write to body. Is it possible via DOM to write a new link rel directive and have it applied on or after the window.onload event? If so can someone please give an example.

I've tried the following;

```
<body>
<script>
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].innerHTML("<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='mycss.css'>");
</script>

<span class="testCSS">This is a test</span>

</body>
```

it doesn't work.

Regards,
shwell.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/512070/add-a-link-stylesheet-dynamically-in-the-head

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`innerHTML` is not a *function*. It's a *property*. Use this:

```
<script>
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].innerHTML += "<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='mycss.css'>";
</script>
```

Comment: Great insight, exact answer.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the  .createElement() and .appendChild() methods.