# How to add JavaScript to change CSS file in R Shiny Application

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I am building a R Shiny app that sometimes will be seen standing alone and sometimes will be viewed in an iframe in another web page. I would like to have a different .css file depending on where it is viewed, so I need to add a JavaScript statement to pick the correct .css. What I have now is:

```
ui.r

headerPanel(winowTitle="PageTitle",

list(tags$head(
tags$script('type = "text/javascript",  if(window.self === window.top) {
 tags$link(rel="stylesheet", type="text/css", href="FullSite.css")} 
 else{ tags$link(rel="stylesheet", type="text/css", href="InFrame.css"})'),

  (other stuff that works)), etc
```

When I run this the application works but it does not read either .css file. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: You are using R code in `tags$script`, which is the reason this does not work. You need to replace the `else` part of the code with `javascript`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is one way to do it. I have replaced the R code in `script` with `javascript`. The first line uses the ternary operator in javascript to set the value of the stylesheet to the appropriate one.

```
list(tags$head(tags$script('type = "text/javascript",
  stylesheet = window.self === window.top ? "FullSite.css" : "InFrame.css"
  $("head").append("<link rel=stylesheet type=text/css href=" + stylesheet + ">") 
')))
```

UPDATE: Here is a better way to add the stylesheet dynamically. I have used this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/512070/add-a-link-stylesheet-dynamically-in-the-head) to modify my answer.

```
  list(tags$head(tags$script('type = "text/javascript"', '
    var ss = document.createElement("link");
    ss.type = "text/css";
    ss.rel = "stylesheet";
    ss.href = window.self === window.top ? "FullSite.css" : "InFrame.css"
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(ss);
  ')))
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not working. The site loads ok, but the css files aren't used. When I check the site source I see: `<script>type = "text/javascript",  stylesheet = window.self === window.top ? "FullSite.css" : "InFrame.css" $("head").append("&lt;link rel=stylesheet type=text/css href=" + stylesheet+ "&gt;")</script>`  It seems that the < and > are not being read correctly.

Comment: Ah okay. You need to escape them. Try escaping the `<` and `>` signs so that they are not converted to `&lt` and `&gt` respectively.

Comment: Sorry, I know next to nothing of javascript - how do I escape them?

Comment: I have added an alternate solution, which should work without any escaping.

Comment: Not a problem. It was a good learning experience for me as well :)