# Update parts of an html page based on the location.href client-side

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have tried searching and nothing I am finding works. the site this is for does NOT work with php, I know how to with php, but I need any other way.

I just want a simple IF THEN statement to say if website is www.a.com then "this style sheet" "this page title" "this logo", etc. I will use the if function many times through the page. if site is a.com, this image, this text, etc.  if is b.com, then everything is different.

I also want it to only recognize the domain itself, so if on a.com/thispage.html , then it would still load with the proper data.

reason being, I have two site pointed to the same folder, which is a store, same product, etc. however we market the product as 'a' and as 'b'. so I just want to see what site the user is on and pull the proper info regarding that site.

this is what I have come up with, but does not generate the required html.

```
<script>
window.onload = function ()
var element = document.getElementbyId('idElement');
if (location.href == "a.com") 
{
  <link href="/landing.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
}
if (location.href == "b.com") 
{
   <link href="/landing2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
}
</script> 

<script>
if (location.href == "a.com") 
{
   <title>AAAAAAAAAAAAA</title>
}
if (location.href == "b.com") 
{
   <title>BBBBBBBBBBBBB</title>
}
</script> 

<script>
if (location.href == "a.com") 
{
   <img src="a.png">
}
if (location.href == "b.com") 
{ 
   <img src="b.png">
}
</script>
```

etc, etc, etc

Comment: @Jan no, it might be asked badly but it's not too broad, that's for sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by having an [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) that holds an object with metadata about each site. When the script runs you [create](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createElement) a new [link element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/512070/add-a-link-stylesheet-dynamically-in-the-head) for the css and add it to the [head](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.head) and set the [document title](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.title).

Do notice that DOM content can only be found (and then changed) after it is loaded, hence the use of an eventlistener for [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/DOMContentLoaded).

This leads to the following implementation in the html script tag:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
NotSet
</title>
<script>
(function () {
    "use strict";
    // have an array sites with data
    var sites = [{
        url: 'a.com',  // if location.href contains this
        title: 'AAAAAAAAAAAAA', // use this title
        css: '/landing.css', // use this css file
        images: [{id: 'idOfImage', src: 'a.png'}] // replace those ids with src 
    }, {
        url: 'b.com',
        title: 'BBBBBBBBBBBBB',
        css: '/landing2.css',
        images: [{id: 'idOfImage', src: 'b.png'}]
    }
        ],
        site, siteIndex, NOT_FOUND = -1;

    //create a link for the css and add it
    function addLink(css) {
        var link = document.createElement('link');
        link.rel = 'stylesheet';
        link.type = 'text/css';
        link.href = css;
        document.head.appendChild(link);
    }

    // find the img tags by id and set the src
    function setImages(images) {
        var image, imgIndex, img;
        for (imgIndex = 0; imgIndex < images.length; imgIndex = imgIndex + 1) {
            image = images[imgIndex];
            img = document.getElementById(image.id);
            if (img !== null) {
                img.src = image.src;
            }
        }
    }

    // iterate over our sites array
    // at the end site will have an object or is null (if no match found)
    for (siteIndex = 0; siteIndex < sites.length; siteIndex = siteIndex + 1) {
        site = sites[siteIndex];
        // is url found in location.href
        if (window.location.href.indexOf(site.url) > NOT_FOUND) {
            break;
        }
        site = null;
    }

    // if we have a site do what is needed
    if (site !== null) {
        addLink(site.css);
        // IE9 or up...
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",
            function () {setImages(site.images); }
            );
        // set the title
        document.title = site.title;
    }
}());
</script>
</head>
<body>
Does this work?
<img id="idOfImage" src="none.png" />
</body>
<html>
```