# Link css file after main content is loaded and parsed

Tags: javascript, css, web, html

Is there any way to link to an external css file but to download and parse it only when the main part of the website have been already loaded?

It is the case of the footer of a website, where its css shouldn't delay the load of the main sections of the page. I know I can inline css code in the HTML code, but in order to have the code organized I prefere not to do it. Is the only way to do this to use a php include?

Same question for Javascript.

Comment: Just insert a `<style>` tag into the document using JavaScript.

Comment: But you'd have to have a crap ton of rules in this external style sheet to make it worthwhile.

Answer (score 0):

Not tried but if you can inject anything into the DOM (DHTML style) you can inject a link tag with the style url of your liking. Not tested but theoretically it should work.

Have a look at:
[Add a link stylesheet dynamically in the <head>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/512070/add-a-link-stylesheet-dynamically-in-the-head)

Hope this answers your question

Answer (score 0):

You can use @import tag after your footer HTML

```
<!--  start footer  -->
<!--  end footer  -->
<style type="text/css">
  @import url("css/footer.css");
</style>
</body>
</html>
```