# How to add Link tag in header?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

```js
        var linkTag = document.createElement ("link");
  linkTag.rel = "canonical";
  linkTag.href = "www.google.com";
  var head = document.getElementsByTagName ("head")[0];
  head.appendChild (linkTag);
```

I have added above code it give me output as `<link rel="canonical" href="www.google.com">` but  I want to close link tag `<link rel="canonical" href="www.google.com" />` like this.

Comment: this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/512111/6582942

Comment: In notion of HTML that doen't make a difference tags are self closing

Comment: That's just how the browser shows it to you.  Add the tag, save the page and then view it in a text editor to see what it really looks like.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to generate the closing tag because it's already there. The browser has already taken your text-based HTML and turned it into a tree of nodes.