# Loading a stylesheet depending on the localStorage item value

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to load one of the many stylesheets depending on the `localStorage` item value:

```
<link rel="" href="assets/css/theme-dark.css" data-toggle="theme" data-theme-mode="dark">
<link rel="" href="assets/css/theme.css" data-toggle="theme" data-theme-mode="light">

<script>
  var themeMode = localStorage.getItem('themeMode');
  var themeFile = document.querySelector('[data-toggle="theme"][data-theme-mode="' + themeMode + '"]');

  themeFile.rel = 'stylesheet';
</script>
```

The code above does work, however the code inside the `<script></script>` tag doesn't seem to fire unless all of the page content is loaded which means that I first see all of the page content unstyled before the stylesheet gets applied. What I want is to get rid of that "flash" effect and make the correct stylesheet apply immediately like it had the `rel="stylesheet"` attribute from the very beginning.

Comment: Maybe try to use cookies instead of localStorage and append the customized stylesheets at backend ?

Comment: @KadirÇetintaş, I have no backend unfortunately as this is a front-end demo only.

Comment: So, something you need to understand is that your script is getting executed AFTER the page is loaded, that's why you see the 'flash'. One solution could be to just have a loading step that waits till your js is executed, then let the user see the ui.

Comment: @leo, I can only thin k of hiding the `body` content. Can you suggest anything smarter than that?

Comment: Create the link tags dynamically, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/512070/add-a-link-stylesheet-dynamically-in-the-head), (the code in the question is correct, please ignore the most voted answer, it's not correct).

Comment: @Teemu, this waits for the page to load until the new stylesheet is applied, so I am getting the same "flash" effect.

Comment: Ah ... stylesheets are also loaded asynchronously. Usually this is not recommended, but you could try write the link tags to the head section with `document.write` ..?

Answer (score -1):

Just show a loading div while you actually go and read the localstorage and apply the right stylesheet.

**Html.**

```
<section hidden>
  Hello, content here!
</section>
```

**Js.**

```
$("document").ready(() => {
    $("section").attr('hidden', false);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qdwv1oLh/2/

Comment: I can't meddle into the design questions so I guess I'd rather `opacity: 0` the body content before everything is loaded.

Answer (score -1):

This is not a solution I was hoping for, but at least it solves the flash issue:

```
<link rel="" href="assets/css/theme-dark.css" data-toggle="theme" data-theme-mode="dark">
<link rel="" href="assets/css/theme.css" data-toggle="theme" data-theme-mode="light">

<style>
  body { visibility: hidden; }
</style>

<script>
  var themeMode = localStorage.getItem('themeMode');
  var themeFile = document.querySelector('[data-toggle="theme"][data-theme-mode="' + themeMode + '"]');

  themeFile.rel = 'stylesheet';

  themeFile.addEventListener('load', function() {
    document.body.style.visibility = 'visible';
  });
</script>
```