# How to Dynamically change the base url of the stylesheet and js files in the head tag on a static website

Tags: javascript

I am working on a static website without making using of SSG and creating all the pages manually when was testing it on a local environment it was fine but when i hosted it i needed to change the domain name and that messed up the location of the files in the head and and the body of the html pages so i was looking up to solve that problem by assigning the base url to a variable and then inserting that in the head tag that didn’t work so i came across this solution

This is what i wanted to achieve
[Add a link stylesheet dynamically in the <head>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/512070/add-a-link-stylesheet-dynamically-in-the-head)

but the problem with this is that i have multiple style sheets and js files and this i not the ideal way to solve it so how can i achieve this without messing up much with the code on my webpage some thing like a variable or append function which lets me add a domain/ base url once and then that takes care of the rest.

Something like this but for a static page

`<link href="<?=getThemeURI()?>/assets/css/theme.css" rel="stylesheet"/>`

I would like to have a js solution if possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

---

with javascript you can grab your current domain with window.location

```
`${window.location.protocol}//${window.location.hostname}`
```

so when you dont need to support old Browsers you can do it the easy way

```
const stylesheets = document.querySelectorAll('link[rel="stylesheet"]');
const domain = `${window.location.protocol}//${window.location.hostname}`
stylesheets.forEach((sheet) => {
  const href = sheet.getAttribute('href');
  sheet.setAttribute('href', `${domain}/${href}`);
});
```

so in your stylesheets you only have to write the path, eg 'assets/css/theme.css'. The Domain will be added via javascript.

if your current domain is not your themeURL then you can setup a config file and grab that information via ajax call from there.

Comment: Hey @manoi when i tried to add multiple files it did not work can you tell me how can i add multiple files

Comment: Hey @manoi can you see what the problem is [link](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GRSA3TSR2XNG) its not working

Comment: you have to set your template strings correct, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals